# Issue with getstream bulk adding activities and "to" field

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to bulk add activities as demonstrated here in the DOCS:

https://getstream.io/docs/?language=php#add-many-activities

The issue is that when I pass different sets of values in the "to" field for each bulk call an error is thrown: "Different values in activity.to".

Is this expected behavior?  I would assume that for a given set of activities bulk added, only the actor field would need to be consistent (to match with the feed).  I am able to add each activity individually so I know that my data syntax is correct.

After some tinkering, if I force the "to" field to be the exact same for each bulk call then it goes through.  This kind of defeats the purpose, however, as each activity might have a different set of "to" recipients depending on the target, etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When adding multiple activities to a feed in a single API request the `to` field should be the same for all the activities that are being added. If you have differing `to` targets use separate API calls to add the activities.